# Customize the format for TFS 2012 Build email alerts

Tags: build, tfs, tfsbuild, build-definition

I am trying to customize the build email alerts in TFS 2012.

I tried editing the files BuildCompletedEvent.xsl and BuildCompletionEvent.xsl in the following location
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Transforms\1033

> for testing I changed the message "Succeeded" to "Succeeded 12345" in the files

Then I restarted the service, and ran a build.
But, still my changes are not getting reflected.

Mail coming with message as "Succeeded" but not the new message.

Where I was wrong...?

Comment: You changed the file on he build server or build agent? Maybe it was the wrong on?

Comment: I did the changes on build agent.

Comment: I think you need to change it on the application server, don't you?

Comment: @DaveShaw, Yes it worked when I edited on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, you need to change the template file on the TFS Application Server(s), the build agents notify the Application Server of the completed event and that sends the alert.

Comment: @DaveShaw is it possible to change it for specific projects not the overall TFS Server. I would like to change the results to include UserStories\Bugs associated with the build.

Answer (score 0):

You can find userful tips on MSDN [Customize the format for TFS email alerts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552337.aspx)